# What are the degeneracy levels of the hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

My textbook stated that the degeneracy level of the hydrogen atom for $n=3$ is $18$.

I'm trying to figure out why it's true. I'm familiar with the Bohr's module but I can't seem to figure out how to does it help me to calculate it. Is there a closed formula to calculate the  degeneracy level of the hydrogen atom? If it's not trivial as I think it is, is there some table that I can use?

Comment: it goes like this s s ps ps dps dps fdps fdps (they repeat twice)where s's start at 1, p's start at 2, d's start at 3 and f's start at 4. so we get 1s 2s 2p 3s 3p 4s 3d 4p 5s 4d 5p 6s.... (just keep adding one to the new alphabet orbital) so for shell 3 we have 3s 3p 3d. s has 2 electrons max (1orbital), p has 6 electrons max (3 orbitals), d has 10 electrons max (5 orbitals).

Answer (score 2):

Your textbook should give you the general result, $2n^2$. Two spin states per orbital, for $n^2$ orbital states. In your case, twice the degeneracy of 3s (1) + 3p (3) + 3d (5), so a total of 9 orbitals.

Yes, there is a famously good reason for this formula, the additional [SO(4) symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector#Quantum_mechanics_of_the_hydrogen_atom) of the hydrogen atom, relied on by Pauli to work out this spectrum before the advent of the Schroedinger equation.  The Bohr model is superbly unhelpful/irrelevant  for this type of calculation.